# conditional select statement in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

I have two tables called order and public holiday as following:

Order Table:

```
OrderId      OrderDate
---------------------------
    1        10 Mar 2017
    2        12 Mar 2017
    3        30 Mar 2017
```

Public Holiday Table:

```
HoliId |     HolidayDate
---------------------------
    1        10 Mar 2017
    1        16 Mar 2017
    1        17 Mar 2017
```

I want to do SQL like following pseudo-code

```
SELECT OrderId, OrderDate, 
if OrderDate is in Holiday Table, 
  then "public holiday" 
  else to_char(to_date(DAY, 'dd/mm/yy'), 'OrderDate')
from Order
```

So the result that I want to have is like following

```
OrderId      OrderDate       DAY
-----------------------------------------
    1        10 Mar 2017     Public holiday
    2        12 Mar 2017     Monday
    3        30 Mar 2017     Friday
```

I want to see if the order date is public holiday based on the public holiday table or not by putting a column

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use an outer join like this:

```
SELECT OrderId,
       OrderDate, 
       case when holidaydate is not null then  'Public holiday' 
             else to_char(OrderDate, 'Day') end as DAY
from orders
     left outer join holidays
        on OrderDate = holiday_date ;
```

If the dates match `holidaydate` is not null so the CASE clause displays your desired string otherwise it displays the day of the `orderdate` .

---

`order` is a reserved word. Presumably your real table has a different name, to avoid the `ora-00903` error. I have used `orders` in my example, so you will need to edit my code to match your table name(s).

Answer (score 0):

Changed the table name of order to ordero as order is a Keyword

```
 select ordero.orderid, ordero.orderdate, holiday.holidaydate,case when holiday.holidaydate is not null then 'Public Holiday'
 else to_char(ordero.orderdate,'Day') end "Day" 
 from ordero left outer join holiday on ordero.orderdate=holiday.holidaydate;
```

Answer (score -1):

Two things to remeber:

1. **ORDER** is a keyword, so please use another table name
2. **CASE** statement should be ended with **END** not with **END AS**

Possible solution:

```
SELECT O.OrderId,
  O.OrderDate,
  CASE
    WHEN H.HolidayDate IS NOT NULL
    THEN 'Public holiday'
    ELSE TO_CHAR(O.OrderDate, 'Day')
  END DAY
FROM ORDER_TABLE O
LEFT JOIN HOLIDAY_TABLE H
ON H.HolidayDate=O.OrderDate;
```

Comment: `AS` is perfectly valid to indicate a column alias

Comment: Accordingly to Oracle SQL Reference CASE statement should be ended with END, not with END AS (although you are right - it works): [CASE statement reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm)

Comment: The `CASE` clause ends with `END`. The `AS` syntax is an optional indicator of a column alias. So `orderId as order_no` is valid alternative to `orderId orderno`. Not sure why you think it matters.